# I want to hide a column in excel using VBA macro in run time but while executing other columns also get selected.

Tags: vba, excel

I want to hide column C based on value in cell AB7.
If value in cell AB7 is 117 then entire column C needs to hide. 
Else I want column C to be there.

```
If Range("AB7").Value = "117" Then
 Columns("C:C").Select
 Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Else
 Columns("C:C").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End If
```

When I run the code columns A:G also get selected. Please let me know if there are any limitations while using the above code. I use excel 2010. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not using select.   `Columns("C:C").Hidden = False` and `Columns("C:C").Hidden = True`